# How can i use Option Tree custom post type checkbox in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
  array(
    'id'          => 'custom_post_type_checkbox',
    'label'       => __( 'Custom Post Type Select', 'theme-text-domain' ),
    'desc'        => sprintf( __( 'Check box' ),
    'std'         => '',
    'type'        => 'custom-post-type-checkbox',
    'section'     => '',
    'rows'        => '',
    'post_type'   => 'newyork-offices',
    'taxonomy'    => '',
    'min_max_step'=> '',
    'class'       => '',
    'condition'   => '',
    'operator'    => 'and'
  ),
```

This is custom post type check box and i got all posts in my page template. so How can i use it my page template ?

What is the loop function for this ?

Comment: you got all posts in my page template. so How can you use it my page template ?. please explain clearly.

Comment: Okay great :) . I have a custom post type called **newyork-offices** i posted many post using this custom post type. That posts show in custom fields meta box with check box in my specific page template. i want to show the post in front end . But i will select the post via check box which post i want. That's why i need to Loop Function for this.

Comment: can you post your frontend code?